# is the a practical way to emulate GO language defer in C or C++ destructors?

Tags: c++, c, go

In short: it is a smart pointers in C question.  Reason: embedded programming and need to ensure that if complex algorithm is used, then proper deallocation occurs with little effort on the developer side.

My favorite feature of C++ is ability to execute a proper deallocation of object allocated on stack and that goes out of scope.  GO language defer provides same functionality and it is a bit closer in spirit to C.

GO defer would be the desired way of doing things in C.  Is there a practical way to add such functionality?

The goal of doing so is simplification of tracking when and where object goes out of scope.  Here is a quick example:

```
struct MyDataType *data = malloc(sizeof(struct MyDataType));
defer(data, deallocator);
if (condition) {
    // dallocator(data) is called automatically
    return;
}
// do something
if (irrelevant) {
    struct DT *localScope = malloc(...);
    defer(localScope, deallocator);
    // deallocator(localScope) is called when we exit this scope
}
struct OtherType *data2 = malloc(...);
defer(data2, deallocator);
if (someOtherCondition) {
    // dallocator(data) and deallocator(data2) are called in the order added
    return;
}
```

In other languages I could create an anonymous function inside the code block, assign it to the variable and execute manually in front of every return.  This would be at least a partial solution.  In GO language defer functions can be chained.  Manual chaining with anonymous functions in C is error prone and impractical.

Thank you

Comment: So you basically want smart pointers or scope exit handlers for C? Not realistic.

Comment: Pretty much.  I was hoping modern C has advanced :)

Comment: You're mixing three languages when really you just want to know if you can run a function when something goes out of scope in C. I'm reasonably certain it's not feasible, but if you want a proper answer, please narrow your question and lose all the Go/C++ exposition (and tags)

Comment: C stays essentially the same as it was back in the 80's.

Comment: You might be able to emulate this with the use of some properly constructed macros, but it would be a manual emulation; you would have to be sure you implemented it in every case. I'm not really sure it would save you very much.

Comment: A proper C version would have to handle `longjmp` somehow, which requires compiler/library support.

Comment: What kind of application are you really coding?

Comment: In C, it's only possible with compiler extensions: http://fdiv.net/2015/10/08/emulating-defer-c-clang-or-gccblocks

Comment: Thank you for all the answers.  The discussion and topics raised have been quite insightful.

Comment: There is a proposal for "defer" mechanism to C and it's in a quite nice shape. It may get "merged" into C23 standard, see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2542.pdf

Answer (score 3):

In C++, I've seen "stack based classes" that follow the RAII pattern.  You could make a general purpose `Defer` class (or struct) that can take any arbitrary function or lambda.

For example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::function;
using std::string;

struct Defer {
  function<void()> action;
  Defer(function<void()> doLater) : action{doLater} {}
  ~Defer() {
    action();
  }
};

void Subroutine(int i) {
  Defer defer1([]() { cout << "Phase 1 done." << endl; });
  if (i == 1) return;
  char const* p = new char[100];
  Defer defer2([p]() { delete[] p; cout << "Phase 2 done, and p deallocated." << endl; });
  if (i == 2) return;
  string s = "something";
  Defer defer3([&s]() { s = ""; cout << "Phase 3 done, and s set to empty string." << endl; });
}

int main() {
  cout << "Call Subroutine(1)." << endl;
  Subroutine(1);
  cout << "Call Subroutine(2)." << endl;
  Subroutine(2);
  cout << "Call Subroutine(3)." << endl;
  Subroutine(3);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Boost has [ScopeExit](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Many different answers, but a few interesting details was not said.

1. Of course destructors of C++ are very strong and should be used very often. Sometime some smart pointers could help you. But the mechanism, that is the most resemble to defer is ON_BLOCK_EXIT/ON_BLOCK_EXIT_OBJ  (see http://http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/generic-change-the-way-you-write-excepti/184403758 ). Do not forgot to read about ByRef.
2. One big difference between C++ and go is when deffered is called. In C++ when your program leaving scope, where is was created. But in go when your program leaving function. That means, this code won't work at all:

   ```
   for i:=0; i < 10; i++ {
     mutex.Lock()
     defer mutex.Unlock()
     /* do something under the mutex */
   }
   ```
3. Of course C does not pretends that is object oriented and therefore there are no destructors at all. It help a lot of readability of code, because you know that your program at line X do only what is written in that line. In contrast of C++ where each closing curly bracket could cause calling of dozens destructors.
4. In C you can use hated statement **goto**. Don't use it for anything else, but it is practical to have cleanup label at the end of function call `goto cleanup` from many places. Bit more complicated is when more than one resource you want do release, than you need more that one cleanup. Than your function finish with

   ```
   cleanup_file:
      fclose(f);
   cleanup_mutex:
      pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
      return ret;
   }
   ```

Comment: Best answer. For C use of goto's is actually the most idiomatic way (and one of legit uses of goto).
Example above uses multiple cleanup labels, but another (better?) approach would be a single cleanup label where all variables are checked/freed. This makes function code cleaner as all it does is `if (x == NULL) { goto cleanup; }` for any kind of `x` and one can write a macro for this so it looks like ENSURE_ALLOCATED(x) or smth like that.

Answer (score 1):

C does not have destructors (unless you think of the GCC specific [variable attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html) `cleanup`, which is weird and rarely used; notice also that the GCC [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) `destructor` is *not* what other languages, C++ notably, call destructor). C++ have them. And **C & C++ are *very different* languages**.

In C++11, you might define your class, having a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)-s, initialized using a [std::initialized_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) of [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (and perhaps dynamically augmented by some [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)). Then its destructor could mimic Go's `defer`-ed statements. But this is not idiomatic.

Go have defer statements and they are idiomatic in Go.

I recommend sticking to the idioms of your programming languages.

<sup>(In other words: don't think in Go while coding in C++)</sup>

You could also embed some interpreter (e.g. [Lua](http://lua.org/) or [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/)) in your application. You might also learn more about [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) techniques and concepts and use them in your software (in other words, design your application with its specific GC).

> Reason: embedded programming and need to ensure that if complex algorithm is used, then proper deallocation occurs with little effort on the developer side.

You might use arena-based allocation techniques, and de-allocate the arena when suitable... When you think about that, it is similar to copying GC techniques.

---

Maybe you dream of some [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) language with a powerful macro system suitable for meta-programming. Then look into Common Lisp.

Comment: Thank you

I have to program an embedded system and I am currently using C++.  Moving to pure C would reduce application footprint a bit and it matters.  I rely on smart pointers and I wish C provided some way to replicate the functionality.  Defer is another form that I am willing to work with.

Comment: @SergeiG i am reminded of a saying - something to do with free lunches and how rare they are

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented a very simple thing like `defer` in golang several days ago.

The only one behaviour different from golang is my `defer` will not be executed when you throw an exception but does not catch it at all. Another difference is this cannot accept a function with multiple arguments like in golang, but we can deal it with lambda capturing local variables.

The implementations are here.

```
class _Defer {
    std::function<void()> __callback;
  public:
    _Defer(_Defer &&);
    ~_Defer();

    template <typename T>
        _Defer(T &&);
};

_Defer::_Defer(_Defer &&__that)
        : __callback{std::forward<std::function<void()>>(__that.__callback)} {
}

template <typename T>
_Defer::_Defer(T &&__callback)
        : __callback{
            static_cast<std::function<void()>>(std::forward<T>(__callback))
        } {
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<T, std::function<void()>>::value,
        "Cannot be convert to std::function<void()>.");
}

_Defer::~_Defer() {
    this->__callback();
}
```

And then I defined some macros to make my `defer` like a keyword in C++ (just for fun)

```
#define __defer_concatenate(__lhs, __rhs) \
    __lhs##__rhs

#define __defer_declarator(__id) \
    if (0);  /* You may forgot a `;' or deferred outside of a scope. */ \
    _Defer __defer_concatenate(__defer, __id) = 

#define defer \
    __defer_declarator(__LINE__)
```

The `if (0);` is used to prevent defer a function out of a scope. And then we can use `defer` like in golang.

```
#include <iostream>

void foo() {
    std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    defer []() {
        std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
    };
    defer foo;
}
```

This will print

```
foo
bar
```

to screen.

Comment: Don't use names that start with `__`; they are reserved.

Answer (score 1):

> GO defer would be the desired way of doing things in C. Is there a practical way to add such functionality?
>
> The goal of doing so is simplification of tracking when and where object goes out of scope.

C does not have any built-in mechanism for automatically invoking any kind of behavior at the end of an object's lifetime.  The object itself ceases to exist, and any memory it occupied is available for re-use, but there is no associated hook for executing code.

For some kinds of objects, that is entirely satisfactory by itself -- those whose values do not refer to other objects with allocated storage duration that need to be cleaned up as well.  In particular, if `struct MyDataType` in your example is such a type, then you get automatic cleanup for free by declaring instances as automatic variables instead of allocating them dynamically:

```
void foo(void) {
    // not a pointer:
    struct MyDataType data /* = initializer */;
    // ...
    /* The memory (directly) reserved for 'data' is released */
}
```

For objects that require attention at the end of their lifetime, it is generally a matter of code style and convention to ensure that you know when to clean up.  It helps, for example, to declare all of your variables at the top of the innermost block containing them, though C itself does not require this.  It can also help to structure your code so that for each object that requires custom cleanup, all code paths that may execute during its lifetime converge at the end of that lifetime.

Myself, as a matter of personal best practices, I always try to write any cleanup code needed for a given object as soon as I write its declaration.

> In other languages I could create an anonymous function inside the code block, assign it to the variable and execute manually in front of every return. This would be at least a partial solution. In GO language defer functions can be chained. Manual chaining with anonymous functions in C is error prone and impractical

C has neither anonymous functions nor nested ones.  It often does make sense, however, to write (named) cleanup functions for data types that require cleanup.  These are analogous to C++ destructors, but you must call them manually.

The bottom line is that many C++ paradigms such as smart pointers, and coding practices that depend on them, simply do not work in C.  You need different approaches, and they exist, but converting a large body of existing C++ code to idiomatic C is a distinctly non-trivial undertaking.

Answer (score 1):

For those using C, I’ve built a preprocessor in C (open source, Apache license) that inserts the deferred code at the end of each block:
https://sentido-labs.com/en/library/#cedro
GitHub: https://github.com/Sentido-Labs/cedro/

It includes a C utility that wraps the compiler (works out-of-the-box with GCC and clang, configurable) so you can use it as drop-in replacement for `cc`, called `cedrocc`, and if you decide to get rid of it, running `cedro` on a C source file will produce plain C. (see the [examples in the manual](https://sentido-labs.com/en/library/cedro/202106171400/#deferred-resource-release))

The alternatives I know about are listed in the “[Related work](https://sentido-labs.com/en/library/cedro/202106171400/#deferred-resource-release-related-work)” part of the documentation:

> Apart from the already mentioned «[A defer mechanism for C](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2020/12/14/a-defer-mechanism-for-c/)», there are macros that use a for loop as `for (allocation and initialization; condition; release) { actions }` [a] or other techniques [b].
>
> [a] “[P99 Scope-bound resource management with for-statements](https://gustedt.gitlabpages.inria.fr/p99/p99-html/utilities.html#blocks)” from the same author (2010), “[Would it be possible to create a scoped_lock implementation in C?](https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/46lpna/would_it_be_possible_to_create_a_scoped_lock/)” (2016), ”[C compatible scoped locks](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=25419916)“ (2021), “[Modern C and What We Can Learn From It - Luca Sas [ ACCU 2021 ] 00:17:18](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpAhX-gsHMs&t=1053s)”, 2021
>
> [b] “[Would it be possible to create a scoped_lock implementation in C?](https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/46lpna/would_it_be_possible_to_create_a_scoped_lock/)” (2016), “[libdefer: Go-style defer for C](https://github.com/trws/libdefer#limitations)” (2016), “[A Defer statement for C](https://github.com/moon-chilled/Defer)” (2020), “[Go-like defer for C that works with most optimization flag combinations under GCC/Clang](https://gist.github.com/jart/aed0fd7a7fa68385d19e76a63db687ff)” (2021)
>
> Compilers like GCC and clang have non-standard features to do this like the [`__cleanup__` variable attribute](https://echorand.me/site/notes/articles/c_cleanup/cleanup_attribute_c.html).

Answer (score 0):

This implementation avoids dynamic allocation and most limitations of other implementations shown here

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>

template<typename F>
struct deferred
{
    std::decay_t<F> f;
    template<typename G>
    deferred(G&& g) : f{std::forward<G>(g)} {}
    ~deferred() { f(); }
};

template<typename G>
deferred(G&&) -> deferred<G>;

#define CAT_(x, y) x##y
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define ANONYMOUS_VAR(x) CAT(x, __LINE__)
#define DEFER deferred ANONYMOUS_VAR(defer_variable) = [&]
```

And use it like

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    DEFER {
        std::cout << "world!\n";
    };
    std::cout << "Hello ";
}
```

Now, whether to allow exceptions in `DEFER` is a design choice bordering on philosophy, and I'll leave it to [Andrei](https://youtu.be/WjTrfoiB0MQ?t=2048) to fill in the details.

Note all such deferring functionalities in C++ necessarily has to be bound to the *scope* at which it is declared, as opposed to Go's which binds to the *function* at which it is declared.